# Match regex in any order in Golang

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds

I have something like this:

```
option name [p1|p2|p3] | [p4]
```

where **option** and **name** are mandatory. **option** must be exactly matched, while **name** is valid any ASCII character combination. Any string after these two is optional if match and it can appear in any order. So, it should match:

```
option name1 p1
option name1 p1 p4
option name1 p4 p1
```

My regex attempt:

```
^(option)\s+(([a-zA-Z0-9]+))\s?(((p1|p2|p3)?)\s?((p4))?)\s?$
```

This works if optional strings are provided in particular order e.g:

```
option name1 p1 p4
option name1
option name1 p1
option name1 p4
```

but this one doesn't work:

```
option name1 p4 p1
```

Is there a way to write regex to support any order of these optional strings?

**Edit**:
p1,p2,p3,p4 are just for example. It could be any of exact strings provided e.g. foo, bar, baz.

**More clarification:**

name could be any string. In perfect scenario it should be different then foo, bar, baz and other options.

Comment: So what differentiates `name1` from `p1`? Do you have a whitelist? What should happen with `option p1`?

Comment: is `option jhfgudfbs4 ^%#*$)` valid?

Comment: It should fail. option and name are mandatory. Other options afterward should be exact matched as I wrote in question. I will update my question, so it is clear.

Comment: It is still not clear whatsoever. You state that "while **name** is valid any ASCII char combination". Well `p1` is an ASCII char combination.

Comment: Did you mean to specify that `name` must be followed by a digit?

Comment: I mean you can chose any letter and digits as combination for name. I updated my question.

Comment: Your question makes even less sense now. If name can be any string then why is `foo` not allowed? `foo` **is** "any string". If you have a whitelist of names and valid string after name then share it because your requirements are impossible to achieve per your question and clarifications.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It might look worst question to you, but I tried to demystify anything that might confuse you. I am not good in regex. That is the reason I asked question. If you read carefully, you could understand as I stated with " Any string after these two is optional if match". So it should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match both variants, you could use an or `|` to list each of the 2 variants.

To make the second part optional you could use an optional non capturing group `(?:...)?`

An example without all the capturing groups:

```
^option\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\s?(?:(?:foo|bar|baz)(?:\s?test)?|test(?:\s?(?:foo|bar|baz))?))?$
```

In parts it will look like

- `^` Start of string
- `option\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match option, 1+ whitespace chars and a+ chars a-zA-Z or digits 0-9
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\s?` Match optional whitespace char
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?:foo|bar|baz)(?:\s?test)?` Match for example for, bar etc and optional test
    - `|` Or
    - `test(?:\s?(?:foo|bar|baz))?` Match test and optionally foo, bar etc
  - `)` Close non capturing group
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make the whole part optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rlKk0m/1)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry for misleading question :( p1,p2,p3 are just examples. In my scenario it should match different strings e.g foo baz bar.

Comment: Why do you use the `p` in the question and in the your regex? In that case you have to list all the options instead of a character class but still use the alternation part to match either one of the left side and one of the right side, or vice versa.

Comment: I tried to simplify it. Since I am not expert in regex, I overlooked this possibility. I will update my question.

Comment: @coder Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/NBgyZe/1

Comment: @coder Then you can make the whole part after it optional https://regex101.com/r/rlKk0m/1

Comment: Yep. That is correct :) Thanks. Accepted & upvoted.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation too :) Couldn't upvote twice :)